# Reactjs props keep getting re-rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am pretty newbie to react and its lifecycles, I am trying to get a specific profile data that created a specific post. I am able to receive data from the profile props but it has a strange behavior.

So when I `console.log(profile)` in render method, profile stays null along with rendering post list, then I get the value from the props, then it goes back to null again and eventually I am able to see the profile that exists. But during that loading, spinner and data blinks based on profile props.

Is it a good a idea to initialize a state with profile props? Or how could remove this behavior?

```
class PostItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getProfileByUserId(this.props.post.user);
  }

  render() {
    const { post } = this.props;
    let username = ''
    const { profile,loading } = this.props.profile;

    if (!profile ) {
       username = (
           <span className={styles['username-style']}>  {post.name + " "}</span>)
    } else {
       username = (
        <Link to={`/profile/${post.user}`} className={styles["profile-link"]}>
           {post.name + " "}
        </Link>)
    }

    let postItemListView = "";
    if (loading) {
       postItemListView = (
       <Grid>
        <Grid.Column>
         <Segment raised>
          <Placeholder>
            <Placeholder.Header image>
              <Placeholder.Line />
              <Placeholder.Line />
            </Placeholder.Header>
            <Placeholder.Paragraph>
              <Placeholder.Line length="medium" />
              <Placeholder.Line length="short" />
            </Placeholder.Paragraph>
          </Placeholder>
        </Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  );
} else {
  postItemListView = (
    <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`}>
      <div className={styles["link-wrapper"]}>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.Column width={16}>
            <Grid.Row style={{ padding: "10px 0" }}>
              <h4 className={styles["subject-style"]}>
                {post.subject.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                  post.subject.slice(1)}
              </h4>
            </Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Row style={{ padding: "10px 0" }}>
              <div className={styles["body-style"]}>{post.text}</div>
            </Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Row>
              <div className={styles["detailed-text__style"]}>
                {username}
                created {moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}
              </div>
            </Grid.Row>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
}

return <div>{postItemListView}</div>;
 }
}

PostItem.propTypes = {
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getProfileByUserId: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   auth: state.auth,
   profile: state.profile
 });

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
 { getProfileByUserId }
 )(React.memo(PostItem));
```

**EDIT:**
This how API requests happen in redux:

```
export const getProfiles = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setProfileLoading());
  axios
    .get(`${PROFILE_API_URL}/all`)
    .then(res =>
       dispatch({
       type: GET_PROFILES,
       payload: res.data
     })
   )
   .catch(err =>
     dispatch({
     type: GET_PROFILES,
     payload: null
   })
  );
 }
```

And this is the reducer for profile:

```
import {
  GET_PROFILE,
  GET_PROFILES,
  PROFILE_LOADING,
  CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE
} from 'actions/types';

const initialState = {
  profile: {},
  profiles: [],
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
     case PROFILE_LOADING:
       return {
          ...state,
          loading: true
       };
       case GET_PROFILE:
        return {
           ...state,
           profile: action.payload,
           loading: false
       };
       case GET_PROFILES:
         return {
           ...state,
           profiles: action.payload,
           loading: false
       };
       case CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE:
         return {
           ...state,
           profile: null
       };
       default:
         return state;
     }
  }
```

Comment: where have you initiated state with props? it doesn't look like you've done this

Comment: and are you making an API request to get the profile data?

Comment: I am making the API request via redux. Let me update it.

Comment: @RedBaron just updated my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ok I'm not entirely sure of the problem in your app but I think you should do something like this

```
class PostItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
      profile: null;
      loading: true;
  }
 }
async componentDidMount() {
    // make api request here and make it async
    await const result = this.props.getProfileByUserId(this.props.post.user); 
    this.setState({profile: result, loading: false})
}

render() loading? (
    <div> Loading... </div>
) : (
    <div>
      <Profile />
    </div>
    )
}
```

slight pseudo code but let me know if that helps?